# How to form PHP curl request for the following command line?

Tags: php, curl, authorization

Can someone help me to form this commndline request in PHP ?

`$ curl -u [USER:PASSWORD] https://subs.pinpayments.com/api/v4/meresheep/subscribers/7388.xml`

I have tried the following and getting only 'false' returned...

```
 // Query the user to pin payments for the details...
 $curl_url = "https://subs.pinpayments.com/api/v4/xyz-site/subscribers/32.xml";

 //open connection
 $ch = curl_init();

 //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: -u [USER:PASSWORD]'));

 //execute post
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` line:

```
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode('username:password')
));
```

Comment: Hello David, Thanks for your reply... i tried in that way too... it is returning 'false' only... But when i access the URL via browser... it asks for username & password and when i entered the username mentioned above and hit enter and it shows me the proper output i wanted on screen... The funniest thing is the same CURL code is working perfectly in my localhost. Is there any additional param that i may have to pass along ?

Comment: You could try outputting the error with echo curl_error($ch); after the curl_exec() line.